# Condition for the perfect triaxial body

Tags: nuclear-physics

Why do a nucleus (body) having asymmetry parameter gamma=30 degree called as perfect triaxial nucleus?

Comment: I've mostly forgotten the details of the $(\gamma,\beta)$ parameterization of nuclear shapes, but I remember this being relatively intuitive.  What resources have you examined so far? Perhaps we can jog my memory.